# How do i add values outside the for loop in PHP

Tags: php, for-loop, dropdown

Is it possible to add values outside the loop. This is not working.

```
<select name="standard" required>
    <option value=''> Select your Standard</option>
    <option value='LKG'>LKG</option>
    <option value='UKG'>UKG</option>
    <?php
    for($std = 1; $std <= 12; $std++){
        echo "<option value='$std'>".$std."</option>";
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Also how do i make the value sit.

```
<?php
for($std = 1; $std <= 12; $std++){
    $selected = ($std == $row['standard']) ? 'selected="selected"' : ''; 
    echo "<option value='$std'" . $selected . ">" . $std . "</option>";
} ?>
```

Comment: Use JavaScript to select Options. If you need stuff to go to the Server first, use AJAX.

Comment: What exactly do you mean add options outside the loop? Loops are the quickest way of adding multiple options where a number increases.

Comment: @PHPglue Is it possible to use without JavaScript and AJAX for now?

Comment: There is a possible problem with your code (some browsers will automatically fix it). There is no space between you value and selected i.e. option value='1'selected="selected"

Comment: Nothing is worth doing incorrectly, even the first time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should perhaps create an array of what you want to loop over and then loop through it with a foreach.

```
<select name="standard" required>
    <option value=''> Select your Standard</option>
    <?php foreach (array_merge(['LKG', 'UKG'], range(1, 12)) as $value) : ?>
    <option value='<?= $value ?>'<?= ($row['standard'] == $value ? ' selected' : '') ?>><?= $value ?></option>
    <?php endforeach ?>
</select>
```

https://3v4l.org/H8BNf

---

You could also do it like the following but its a little messy.

```
<select name="standard" required>
    <option value=''> Select your Standard</option>
    <option value='LKG'<?= ($row['standard'] == 'LKG' ? ' selected' : '') ?>>LKG</option>
    <option value='UKG'<?= ($row['standard'] == 'UKG' ? ' selected' : '') ?>>UKG</option>
    <?php
    for($std = 1; $std <= 12; $std++){
        echo "<option value='$std'".($row['standard'] == $std ? ' selected' : '').">".$std."</option>".PHP_EOL;
    }
    ?>
</select>
```

Comment: How silly! i did not think of the second method. Its neat. Thank You!